Showing that limit point of a set that is not closed must converge in metric space even if it is not complete
The problem statement is:
Let $ (x_{n}) \subseteq (X, \delta) $ be a Cauchy sequence. Suppose that the set $\{x_{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is not closed. Show that there necessarily exists $x \in X$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.
My attempt at a solution
In a complete metric space, every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit point within that space. Therefore, if $ (X, \delta) $ is complete, the sequence $ (x_n) $ must converge to some $ x \in X $. However, if the space is not complete, then $ (x_n) $ may not converge to a point within $ X $. It may be that it converges to a point outside $ X $.
A set not being closed means that there exists a limit point of the set that is not contained within $ \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} $. For sequence $ (x_n) $ to converge to $ x $,  point $ x $ doesn't have to be one of the terms in the sequence $ (x_n) $; it only has to be an element of $ X $. Therefore, if $ (X, \delta) $ is a complete metric space, then the Cauchy sequence $ (x_n) $ will  converge to some $ x \in X $, even though the set $ \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is not closed. The fact that the set is not closed suggests that the limit $ x $ may not be one of the $ x_n $, but convergence still occurs within $ X $.
On the other hand, if $ (X, \delta) $ is not complete, there is no guarantee that $ (x_n) $ will converge to a point in $ X $. The sequence could  "escape" to a point outside of $ X $.
Therefore, there does not necessarily exist $ x \in X $ such that $ x_n \rightarrow x $ unless $ X $ is a complete metric space.
I know that this proof is incorrect since the problem statement asks to show that x must be in X, but I do not understand why this is wrong. Essentially the proof follows the same logic as saying that the limit point may not be in a set that is not closed, but although it may not be in the set, according to the problem statement it has to be in X. Can anyone please explain why this is incorrect and if there any any alternative strategies to prove the statement?
Thank you for your help.

Let me make a few suggestions. You are confusing yourself by pondering issues that are not relevant to the problem. So, take a red pencil and cross out all references to these two things: completeness of $X$ (the problem statement doesn't say whether $X$ is complete, so that's irrelevant); points outside of $X$ (the problem statement is not about points outside of $X$, so they are irrelevant). Don't be distracted by these issues. Constrain your thinking to the metric space $X$ itself, and its points. In particular, focus on the job: proving that ${x_n}$ converges to $x$.

As a further comment on your final paragraph, you already have a point $x$ in $X$, namely a limit point of the set ${x_n}$.

@Snoop: ${1/n}$ is a closed subset of $(0,\infty)$.

"Therefore, there does not necessarily exist x∈X such that xn→x unless X is a complete metric space."  No one says there must be one.  But no-one said there can't be one.  You have to prove that a cauchy sequence with a specific condition (it is not closed) must converge.  (But cauchy sequences that are closed don't have to).

"How is X=(0,∞),δ=|.|,xn=1/n not a counterexample? What am I missing? "  You are missing that ${x_n|x_n = \frac 1n}$ IS closed in $X$

You bring up that ${x_n}$ has a limit point $x$ that is not an element of ${x_n}$.  And then you... just drop it.  Keep at it.  It's key to your proof.  Indeed just using the psychology of math text, I'd bet without doing any work, that we are supposed to prove ${x_n}\to x$.  ... Now as to you counter example of ${\frac 1n}$ and $X = (0,\infty)$.  Is there a limit point of ${\frac 1n}$ that is not in ${\frac 1n}$? [Answer: No. there isn't... because ${\frac 1n}$ is closed.]

And as a counter example to you counter example.  $\mathbb Q$ is not complete.  ${\frac 1n}\subset \mathbb Q$.   And yet ${\frac 1n}$ does converge to $0\not \in {\frac 1n}$.  But, hey!, $0$ is a limit point!  $0$ is a limit point that demonstrates that ${\frac 1n}$ is not closed.

$\require{cancel}$
My attempt at a solution
In a complete metric space, every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit point within that space. Therefore, if (X,δ)
is complete, the sequence (xn) must converge to some x∈X. However, if the space is not complete, then (xn) may not converge to a point within X. It may be that it converges to a point outside X
.
A set not being closed means that there exists a limit point of the set that is not contained within {xn∣n∈N}
. For sequence (xn) to converge to x, point x doesn't have to be one of the terms in the sequence (xn); it only has to be an element of X. $\cancel{\text{Therefore}}_{\color{red}{\text{what follows comes just from the definition of complete. It doesn't follow from what you have just stated. Therefore "therefore" is not the correct word to use}}}$, $\cancel{\text{if (X,δ) is a complete metric space, then the Cauchy sequence (xn) will converge to some x∈X, even though the set {xn∣n∈N} is not closed. The fact that the set is not closed suggests that the limit x may not be one of the xn, but convergence still occurs within X}}_{\color{red}{\text{Irrelevant leave this out}}}$
.
On the other hand, if (X,δ)
is not complete, there is no guarantee that (xn) will converge to a point in X. The sequence could "escape" to a point outside of X
.
Therefore, there does not necessarily exist x∈X
such that xn→x unless X
is a complete metric space.
$\color{red}{\text{or if there is something specific about that particular sequence.  Such as... it is not closed. }}$
=====
Now... you have already shown that $\{x_n\}$ has a limit point $x$ that is not an element of $\{x_n\}$ (which makes it different for just any old generic Cauchy sequence in this, maybe, incomplete metric space).  So use it.
$x$ is a limit point of $\{x_n\}$.  That means for any $\epsilon > 0$ then $N_{\epsilon}x = \{w|d(x,w) < \epsilon\}$ must contain some points of $\{x_n\}$
And $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. That means for any $\epsilon_2 > 0$ there is an $N_{\epsilon_2}$ so that for any  $m,n> N_{\epsilon_2}$ we have $d(x_n,x_m)< \epsilon_2$.
And we want to prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges to some $w\in X$.  That means for any $\epsilon_3$ we can find an $N_{\epsilon_3}$ so that for all $n> N_{\epsilon_3}$ we have $d(w,x_n)< \epsilon_3$.
Can we tie those all together?  What if we try to prove that $x_n\to x$ ($x$ being that limit point not in $\{x_n\}$ that you [successfully] demonstrated must exist).  Can we tie those together?
Hint: Let $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon=\epsilon_3$.  Let $\epsilon_2=\frac 12 \epsilon$.
Hint: Triangle inequality.  $d(x, x_n)\le d(x, x_m)+d(x_m,x_n)$ and $d(x,x_m) \le d(x,x_n) + d(x_m,x_n)$
